# Printing problem

Tags: printing

I am a noob on the Pi system.
I have installed CUPS on my Pi3.  I run CUPS and added a network printer (HP Laserjet 1320).  I can send a test print from CUPS to the printer and all is good.
The problem is no printer shows up in the list of printers LibreOffice Writer.  What have I done or not done to cause this problem?